# ¿Cómo crear un árbol de usuarios en base a sus relaciones de Google+?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-plus

Antes que nada perdonad si mi preguta es trivial. He sido muy autodidacta con el tema de google scripts y hay cosas básicas que a veces me fallan.

Quiero crear un Google Apps Script que coja todos los usuarios públicos que están en los círculos de un usuario concreto los ponga en una lista y luego vaya creando un árbol de usuarios hasta cierto nivel (2 o 3 ). La idea es poder saber qué amigos en común pueden tener personas que están en los círculos de otra.

El problema lo tengo directamente cuando intento pillar los usuarios del círculo. He pillado el código de ejemplo de google y funciona correctamente, pero cuando le pido que pille otro usuario me dice que:

"Only allowed to fetch the authenticated user's visible circles. (línea 6, archivo "Código")"

El código que he usado es este:

```
function getPeople() 
{
  var userId = '109327498406159632838';
  var people, pageToken;
  do {
     people = Plus.People.list(userId, 'visible', {
     pageToken: pageToken
     });
     if (people.items) {
        for (var i = 0; i < people.items.length; i++) {
        var person = people.items[i];
        Logger.log(person.displayName);
        }
     } else {
         Logger.log('No people in your visible circles.');
    }
      pageToken = people.nextPageToken;
   } while (pageToken);
}
```

Y este es el link a la página de google plus a la que quiero acceder: https://plus.google.com/109327498406159632838/posts  que es la página oficial de seguidores de este blog: http://googleappscriptsweb.blogspot.com.es/

Parece que sea un tema de permisos pero no tiene mucho sentido dado que manualmente podrías ir circulando por cientos de usuarios que no conoces hasta llegar donde quisieras.

Se me ha ocurrido que se podría hacer parseando el `html` de las páginas pero me parece una locura.

¿Alguien podría arrojar un poco de luz sobre que estoy haciendo mal o que posible solución tengo?

Gracias

Comment: A raíz de esta pregunta he investigado un poco sobre esto. Me parece que es necesario crear una aplicación y que el usuario del perfil correspondiente autorice que esta pueda ver las personas en sus círculos. Tal vez demasiado complicado comparado usar alguna herramienta para analizar el código fuente, como podría ser mediante la función IMPORTXML de las hojas de cálculo de Google.

Comment: Es lo que me temia... aunque el usuario puede navegar tranquilamente por todo el mundo de amigos de amigos de amigos, a nivel de script necesitamos el permiso explicito.... Por parseo de html... inviable... lo he intentado pero es imposible... gracias por molestarte en mirarlo!!

Comment: Me parece que aún no somos muchos los que estamos mirando [tag:google-apps-script]. Tal vez tengas más respuestas si intentas usando Google+ API con Java, PHP u otro lenguaje con mayor número de seguidores.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo... intentaré mirarlocon otros lenguajes a ver....

Answer (score 2):

El método [**people.list()**](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/list) actualmente solo permite el valor de `me` en `userId`  a pesar de que cualquier persona en el mundo puede ver la lista de personas que el propio usuario ha hecho público desde Google+ en Web, pero aun no es posible vía el API. Dejo el [enlace](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=529) a la mejora.

Comment: Gracias por mirartelo.... se te ocurre alguna manera para parchearlo? Yo lo he mirado por diferentes maneras pero no lo he encontrado